# Using commas in grid column

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, int, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I currently have a grid with a column that has larger numbers (1000+).

My customer recently asked me to make that column have commas within those numbers.  I know you can change the number into a string, however, I do some mathematical work as well with that column, so I would prefer not changing the number from an int to a string and then reverse it again.

The grid I'm using is a Telerik Extensions MVC grid.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Format()` method, and pass your [desired format](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/globalization/numberformatting) to it. (but you have to test your format against the culture settings because formats are culture-dependent)

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<YourModel>().Name("YourGridName").Columns(columns =>
{
...
// this format puts group separator for large numbers
columns.Bound(p => p.LargeNumberField).Title("LargeNum").Format("{0:0,00}");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
Format("{0:N0}") 
only because I get error for negative number as my numbers are not always larger than 1000.

Warr's answer can be userful too.
[How to add in KendoUI MVC Grid a thousand comma separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35949325/how-to-add-in-kendoui-mvc-grid-a-thousand-comma-separator)