# How to add in KendoUI MVC Grid a thousand comma separator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to display 1000 like 1,000 in Grid (Must have commas). Initial data type is string. I need thousand comma separator.

I have the same questions as in 
[How to change display format of long variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18227019/how-to-change-display-format-of-long-variable). But my data type is string.

In this topic they did not have clear answer for KendoUI MVC Grid
for thousand comma separator.

I have KendoUI Grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid((IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.MyModel>)ViewBag.QualReq)
    .Name("MyGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
        { 
        columns.Bound(p => p.Actual); 
        })
    .DataSource(d => d
        .Ajax()
    )
)
```

Model

```
public class MyModel
{ 
    public virtual string Actual { get; set; } 
}
```

Controller

```
    [OutputCache(Duration = 60)]
    public ActionResult MyActionMethod(int RankId = 0)
    { 
        . . .                  
        ViewBag.QualReq = qualificationRequirements.Where(x => x.RankID == RankId).ToList();
        . . .
```

I have not found any information for MVC Grid in Number Formatting topic.
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/numberformatting

Answer (score 1):

The number formatting document you link to is showing how you would do this in JavaScript. Part of the problem you're running in to is that you are using a string property to store numeric data. You need to change your `Actual` property to be an `int` (or some other numeric type) instead of a `string` and then add a `DisplayFormat` attribute `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N2}")]`.

The thing to keep in mind though, is that without setting the culture, it's going to use whatever the thread's current culture is (presumably en-US since you want to use a comma as the separator) to determine what the separator character should be. If you need it to be something different (for a different culture), you're going to need to set the culture explicitly.

Comment: [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N2}")]
    public virtual string Actual { get; set; } is not working for me

Comment: I updated my answer. The problem is that your `Actual` property is a string, so the formatting is, effectively, ignored. If the value is meant to be numeric, you should use one of the numeric data types to store it.

Comment: It was the question: How to format 1000 like 1,000 if data type is a string?

Comment: You really can't without first somehow changing the data type to be numeric. Why does the data type need to be a string?

Comment: The data has values like words, for example  "active" and numbers.

Comment: In that case, you're going to need to create your own custom attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this on the grid itself with ClientTemplate.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid((IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.MyModel>)ViewBag.QualReq)
    .Name("MyGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
        { 
            columns.Bound(p => p.Actual).ClientTemplate("#= kendo.format('{0:N0}', parseInt(Actual)) #"); 
        })
    .DataSource(d => d
        .Ajax()
    )
)
```

If this field sometimes contains non-numeric data, you may want to include some logic to account for those cases.

Answer (score 0):

set **.Format("{0:n0}")** in Columns Kendo Grid

```
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(c => c.Price).Format("{0:n0}"); 
})
```